# System.Xml.XmlException when I run Open function of ServiceHost (WCF) in C#

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a problem when I moved my code from one computer (A) to the other (B). The problem is that I got the following exceptions when the code run to Open function of the ServiceHost., though the service still can be turned on. In other words, this exception does not affect the service. This problem does not happen in computer A.

```
Exception thrown: 'System.Xml.XmlException' in System.Xml.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Xml.XmlException' in System.Xml.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Xml.XmlException' in System.Xml.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Xml.XmlException' in System.Xml.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Xml.XmlException' in System.Xml.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Xml.XmlException' in System.Xml.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Xml.XmlException' in System.Xml.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Xml.XmlException' in System.Xml.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Xml.XmlException' in System.Xml.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Xml.XmlException' in System.Xml.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Xml.XmlException' in System.Xml.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Xml.XmlException' in System.Xml.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Xml.XmlException' in System.Xml.dll
```

I create my own TRFServiceHost which inherents from ServiceHost as follow

```
public class TRFServiceHost : ServiceHost
{
    private string _configureFilePath;

    public TRFServiceHost(Type serviceType, params Uri[] baseAddresses) : base(serviceType, baseAddresses)
    {
    }

    protected override void ApplyConfiguration()
    {
        this._configureFilePath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ApplicationBase +
                                  "TRFServerModule.config";
        if (!File.Exists(this._configureFilePath))
        {
            base.ApplyConfiguration();
            return;
        }
        var configFileMap = new ExeConfigurationFileMap { ExeConfigFilename = this._configureFilePath };
        var config = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(configFileMap,
            ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
        var serviceModel = ServiceModelSectionGroup.GetSectionGroup(config);
        if (serviceModel == null)
        {
            base.ApplyConfiguration();
            return;
        }
        foreach (ServiceElement serviceElement in serviceModel.Services.Services)
        {
            this.LoadConfigurationSection(serviceElement);
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Then I call this class as follow:

```
try
        {
            if (this._trfServiceHost == null)
                this._trfServiceHost = new TRFServiceHost(typeof(TRFServerService));

            if (this._trfServiceHost.State != CommunicationState.Opened)
            {
                this._trfServiceHost.Open();
                message = "TRF Service has been turned on.";
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            message = "TRF Service cannot be turned on. " + e.Message;
        }
```

The config file is as follow:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <netTcpBinding>
    <binding sendTimeout="00:10:00" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
      <security mode="None"></security>
    </binding>
  </netTcpBinding>
</bindings>
<services>
  <service name="TRFServerModule.TRFServerService">
    <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" contract="TRFCommonLibs.ITRFService"></endpoint>
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="net.tcp://127.0.0.1:4530"/>
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
</services>
```

Thank you.